# Is there any real difference between implementing http and https from a programming point of view?

Tags: ssl, https, client-server, communication

I understand the basics of SSL and http, but in terms of handshakes and encryption, is it completely handled once a server is set up for SSL? Or is there generally code that needs be in place to trigger these events on both client and server side?

For a description of the situation:
I have a main application that will run on a server that will keep track of multiple applications implemented on separate machines, which have internet access. Occasionally I want the multiple applications to report back to the main application in the form of a string. The reason Im asking for a very general answer is because the platform I'm using (Servoy) doesn't have any plain examples of this being done.

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS is basically a channel which is secured using encryption key.
If you are transferring confidential data then you need to use HTTPS as HTTP is Hacky.

I am sure you must be aware how HTTPS works, if it's configured correctly then its a charm to play on.

The situation what you have mentioned is being used is most of my projects I work around, SSL is a must have if you play around with confidential data, if not then go for HTTP.

HTTPS is bit slow when we compare it with HTTP, so it's a call based on requirement.